# Git apagou minhas pastas

Tags: git, github

Dei um `git status` no repositório e apareceu isso:
Não sei como isso aconteceu, mas quero as pastas de volta (não cheguei a colocar `git add .` ainda)

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    .idea/.gitignore
        deleted:    .idea/inspectionProfiles/profiles_settings.xml
        deleted:    .idea/misc.xml
        deleted:    .idea/modules.xml
        deleted:    .idea/python.iml
        deleted:    .idea/vcs.xml
        deleted:    .vscode/settings.json
        deleted:    README.md
        deleted:    aula01.py
        deleted:    aula02.py
        modified:   aula04.ipynb
        deleted:    datasets/kc_house_data.csv
        deleted:    datasets/mapa_house.html
        deleted:    datasets/mapa_house_aula02.html
        deleted:    datasets/question_aula02.csv
        deleted:    datasets/report_aula02.csv
```

Comment: Bom, _provavelmente_ alguém apagou os arquivos e agora o `git` está dizendo que eles foram apagados... Na própria mensagem tem a dica para reverter: _use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory_ - ou seja, tente rodar `git restore arquivos` (ou `git restore .` se quiser resgatar todos - lembrando que se fizer para "todos", ele também vai desfazer a alteração do arquivo que está modified, então talvez seja melhor fazer somente para os deleted)

Comment: Você chegou a alterar o nome da pasta, mudar o diretório ou algo relacionado? Pois por exemplo, se você renomear a pasta `datasets`, o `git` irá entender que a pasta `datasets` foi deletada/excluída e que uma nova pasta `nome-da-copia` foi criada/adicionada. Se este caso não se encaixa com o seu, sugiro o que o @hkotsubo mencionou.